# Distinguishing 0s (zero) from NAs in an igraph adjacency matrix

Tags: r, matrix, igraph

I want to create an adjacency matrix which contains the edge weights from an `igraph` graph object so that I can plot a heatmap. Some of my edge weights are 0, however, so I want a sparse matrix which uses `NA`s instead of 0s.

Example data:

```
gg1 <- graph_from_literal(a-+b, b-+c, b-+d, c-+d, d-+a, d-+e)
gg1 <- set.edge.attribute(gg1, "weight", value = c(1, 3, 2, 0, -2, 0))
as_adjacency_matrix(gg1, attr = "weight", sparse = T)

   a b c d e
a  0 1 0 0 0
b  0 0 3 2 0
c  0 0 0 0 0
d -2 0 0 0 0
e  0 0 0 0 0
```

`[c,d]` and `[d,e]` are the only legit 0s, everything else I want as `NA`. `as_adjacency_matrix` is great, but is there any way to have it populate the cells of "non-existent edges" with `NA` instead of 0?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cludgy, but hey...

```
gg1 <- graph_from_literal(a-+b, b-+c, b-+d, c-+d, d-+a, d-+e)
gg1 <- set.edge.attribute(gg1, "weight", value = c(1, 3, 2, 0, -2, 0))
gg1 <- as_adjacency_matrix(gg1, attr = "weight", sparse = T)

gg1 <- formatSpMatrix(gg1, zero.print = "NA")
class(gg1) <- "numeric"

#    a  b  c  d  e
# a NA  1 NA NA NA
# b NA NA  3  2 NA
# c NA NA NA  0 NA
# d -2 NA NA NA  0
# e NA NA NA NA NA
```